# Incidences vs incidents

Tags: word-usage

I will analyze the number of incidents of traffic accidents which occurred last year.

I will analyze the incidences of traffic accidents which occurred last year.

Are these sentences using the words correctly?

Comment: +1 I thought for sure this would be a duplicate, but it looks like we're one of the few English sites out there who [haven't](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=incidents%20or%20incidences) addressed this topic.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet this question will be the top Google result within a week if it gets a good answer.

Comment: You will analyze neither. Instead you will analyze the number of traffic accidents, or just the traffic accidents, plain and simple. "Incidences of accidents that occurred" is saying the same thing thrice.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Surely you would agree that a traffic accident is an incident.  You could even analyze the incident, but you wouldn't be analyzing its frequency, as an incident is by definition a single event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Incidence* refers to the *frequency* of something happening.

> **[Incidence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incidence)** *noun* : the number of times something happens or develops : the rate at which something occurs

An *incident* is an event.

> **[Incident](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incident)** *noun* an unexpected and usually unpleasant thing that happens

Your usage is on the right path.

**Usage A**

> I will analyze the number of incidents of traffic accidents which occurred last year.

This is correct, but sounds a bit clumsy. You could just say:

> I will analyze the number of *traffic accidents* which occured last year.

or

> I will analyze the number of *traffic accident incidents* that occurred last year.

**Usage B**

> I will analyze the incidences of traffic accidents which occurred last year.

You should use singular *incidence*.

> I will analyze the *incidence* of traffic accidents which occurred last year.

You are analyzing the frequency of a single metric - traffic accidents.

You would use *incidences* if you were analysing multiple metrics.

> I will analyze the *incidences* of *traffic accidents, plane crashes, and boating accidents*, that occurred last year.

Comment: ... Apart from the fact that it ignores the other relevant sense of incidence (listed **first** by AHDEL): _incidence_ n.
1. The act or an instance of happening; occurrence: _did not expect criticism and was surprised by its incidence_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's interesting.      [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/incidence) doesn't list that definition at all.  Thanks very much for your response.

Comment: @Lumberjack Doubtless it's in OED if it's in AHDEL and RHK Webster's. ODO doesn't have the same coverage.

Answer (score 4):

Though one seldom sees the plural of "incidence", here is an example of its use:

“The incidence of measles in the U.S. was ‘x’ people per thousand in 2015. The incidence of mumps was ‘y’ people per thousand in 2015. These **incidences** were much worse than they should have been.”

Answer (score 0):

I just don't believe that incidences should ever be used.  It just doesn't really make sense.  Our English language is really odd.  For example words take and bring. Also, I go crazy when I hear people referred to as "that" instead of "who."  It is "he is the one WHO, not THAT," and even some of the most educated people use the incorrect word.

Comment: Perhaps they're so educated that they've discovered that the person who first stated the rule didn't have the authority they claimed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such word as "incidences". Incidents is the plural of incident. Incidence is not a word commonly used and refers usually to medical issues e.g. The incidence of measles in the community has increased due to irresponsible parents deciding not to vaccinate their children against the disease.

Comment: As shown in Neil's answer, "incidence" does indeed have a plural.

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple Mac dictionary--which I believe is based on Merriam-Webster.

incidence   ˈinsidəns

noun

1  the occurrence, rate, or frequency of a disease, crime, or something else undesirable: *an increased incidence of cancer.*

• the way in which the burden of a tax falls upon the population: *the entire incidence falls on the workers.*

2   Physics the intersection of a line, or something moving in a straight line, such as a beam of light, with a surface.  See also angle of incidence.

ORIGIN late Middle English (denoting a casual or subordinate event or circumstance): from Old French, or from medieval Latin incidentia, from Latin incidere ‘fall upon, happen to’ (see incident ).  Sense 1 dates from the early 19th cent.

USAGE **Incidence** and **incidents** sound the same, but **incidence** is more often used in technical contexts, referring to the frequency with which something occurs: *increased ultraviolet light is likely to cause increased incidence of skin cancer.*  **Incidents** is simply the plural of **incident**, an event: *the police are supposed to investigate any incidents of domestic violence.*  The form **incidences** should be avoided.